# Reactivity of different alcohols with NaNH2 and CH3I

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, alcohols, reactivity, ethers

> Identify the final product (B) in the following reaction:
>
> [image: question]

I'm not sure how $\ce{NaNH2}$ and $\ce{CH3I}$ will react with the different types of alcohol present here. According to my solution,ether was formed in place of $\ce{CH2OH}$ in the end, whereas the answer says that $\ce{CH2OH}$ group will remain unaffected. What am I doing wrong? Can anyone explain to me the full mechanism?

Comment: Tertiary alcohols are usually more reactive than primary alcools.

Comment: But the pKa of primary alcohols is lower  see http://evans.rc.fas.harvard.edu/pdf/evans_pKa_table.pdf.    In real life I would not expect much selectivity in this reaction.

Comment: t-BuOH is more acidic than primary alcohols in the gas phase but not in solution.

Comment: Per my answer, a more likely explanation relates to an issue with reagents and/or procedure.

Comment: I had since edited my answer, and in particular, suggest checking the quality of the NaNH2 given its sensitivity to moisture/water/air.

Comment: Sodium amide is more than strong enough of a base to generate the primary alkoxide, which is stabilized best by solvation, so your proposed methylation at this position is perfectly viable. Cold $\ce{KMnO4}$ will leave the tertiary alcohol untouched and oxidizes the secondary one to the ketone.

Answer (score -6):

I suspect, possibly just to a minor extent, that you have also managed to produce an expected photolysis product here (see below).

Interestingly, the [photo sensitive methyl iodide](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1747587), in the presence of a suitable catalyst ($\ce{CO2, Cu,}$..) with lab light (rich in UV) may have commenced in a radical reaction chain in the presence of ethanol:

$$\ce{CH3I ->[$h \nu$] ^.CH3 + I^.}$$

$$\ce{C2H5OH + I^. -> HI + C2H5O^.}$$

$$\ce{C2H5O^. + C2H5O^. -> (C2H5)2O2}$$

$$\ce{(C2H5)2O2 + ^.CH3 -> (C2H5)2O + CH3O^.}$$

....(the reaction chain continues)

where, I have stopped at the formation of Ether, albeit possibly created in very small amounts but detectable by its smell, nevertheless.

Repeat the experiment controlling for light/catalyst and see if you can still smell the Ether.

My advice, any time working with a photoreactive iodides, be mindful of light exposure.

[EDIT] The implication of my analysis, check your product yields, reagents and procedure, as a minor photo-induced side product may not (but still could) be connected to your results. In particular, I would start with the $\ce{NaNH2}$ as [per Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_amide):

> $\ce{NaNH2 + H2O → NH3 + NaOH}$
>
> $\ce{4 NaNH2 + 7 O2 → 2 Na2O + 4 NO2 + 4 H2O}$

which suggests that either exposure to moisture/water/air can degrade the compound.

Comment: I can't see how it answers OP question?

Comment: I have edited my comments. My answer clearly presents an understandable analysis and further notes it may NOT be even related to the poor results. So, look elsewhere and do remove the light factor.

Comment: No step is photochemically-induced free radical reaction. First there will be acid-base reaction, followed by SN reaction and finally oxidation.. These type of questions aren't to know possible issues with reactants or procedure, rather what final product wil be and why?

Comment: Zenix: My edited answer points to NaNH2 (which readily degrades). Your comment is definitely valid if it is even apparent that the reaction is at all proceeding. But with only a minor photolysis side product being created, this suggests to me that the reaction may, indeed, not be proceeding!

Comment: On further thought, the ethanol employed (the source of the Ether per a radical mechanism) may not be absolute, the source of water.

Comment: Zenix, thanks for discounting the photo radical path leading to the report of Ether. I readily await your claimed path and, if you can't, I even more readily await that admission, so I could postulate other routes.

Comment: The issue is that the reaction hasn't actually been done in reality and is just a hypothetical paper-pen reaction.. So, it is ideal conditions outside the reaction..